# detect and replace affiliate ID from URLs

Tags: php

I was trying to detect affiliate ID from URLs for a website running in PHP.
the URL examples are

I have changed the affiliate ID into real ones.

```
https://flipkart.com/product-name/product-id?marketplace=FLIPKART&affid=honor&ppn=something
https://flipkart.com/product-name/product-id?marketplace=FLIPKART&affid=apple&ppn=something
https://flipkart.com/product-name/product-id?marketplace=FLIPKART&affid=sony&ppn=something
```

I want to replace it with `affid=sthachilo`

These URLs will be saved in database.
So I cant use `$_GET["affid"]`

when the URL is shown, I just want to replace the affiliate ID.
or I can use it to replace the affiliate ID and save it in the database.
But I dont know how to detect the `affid=` section and replace whatever is there.

I tried the following code, but it doesnt seems to be working

```
    $url = "https://flipkart.com/product-name/product-id?marketplace=FLIPKART&affid=sony&ppn=something";
    $newurl = preg_replace('/&affid=(\d+)/','&affid=sthachilo',$url);
    echo $newurl;
```

Here is a real URL example with my affiliate ID in it.

```
https://www.flipkart.com/complan-kesar-badam/p/itmew2cdj5dmthjk?marketplace=FLIPKART&iid=e6c16ab0-c15d-49c2-843e-cf4a5104c53b.MDMETGN5YZZ5MRYG.SEARCH&ppt=browse&lid=LSTMDMETGN5YZZ5MRYGTBFFJO&srno=b_1_1&pid=MDMETGN5YZZ5MRYG&affid=sthachilo&ssid=7bwqga35j40000001588133282410&ppn=browse
```

atleast I want to remove everything after `itmew2cdj5dmthjk`
and add affiliate ID at the end.
for example

```
https://www.flipkart.com/complan-kesar-badam/p/itmew2cdj5dmthjk?affid=sthachilo
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot replace single element in the url , to have break the url and add complete url

Comment: Your regex should be `/&affid=user\d+/`

Comment: The user1, user2, user3 is just examples.
The real affiliate ID is just text without numbers.

Comment: Which real affiliate ID? The one you are searching for or the one you are replacing it with? It would be much easier if you gave us real data to work with rather than samples that don't match reality.

Comment: I have updated affiliate ID examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the url parts and than use [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the url query

```
$url = "https://flipkart.com/product-name/product-id?marketplace=FLIPKART&affid=sony&ppn=something";
// parse url
$parse = parse_url($url);
// parse the query
parse_str($parse['query'], $query);
// replace the affid with your desired value
$query['affid'] = 'samsung';
// rebuild the query
$parse['query'] = http_build_query($query);
// rebuild the final url
$final_url = $parse['scheme'].'://'.$parse['host'].$parse['path'].'?'.$parse['query'];
echo $final_url
// output : https://flipkart.com/product-name/product-id?marketplace=FLIPKART&affid=samsung&ppn=something
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the given affiliate ID with `android`:

```
$url = "https://flipkart.com/product-name/product-id?marketplace=FLIPKART&affid=apple&ppn=something";

$newurl = preg_replace('/&affid=(.+)?&/','&affid=android&',$url);
```

Probably not the best way to do it since it assumes `affid` is surrounded by `&` but if you know that will always be the case then this will work.